# AlpineJS x-data on tr set, x-show working, but x-on:click not working EDIT: table is using DatatablesJS

Tags: html, datatables, alpine.js

I'm fairly new with AlpineJS. I've read in the docs that x-on, x-show, etc should be inside a parent with an x-data directive. I was trying to make a dropdown inside a td of a table. Here is the code snippet:

```
<tr x-data="{open:false}">
      <td>
         <button class="bg-transparent" x-on:click="open = !open">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
         </button>
         <div class="flex flex-column bg-white" x-show="open">
            <a href="#">Update Job</a>
            <a href="#">Delete Job</a>
         </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Right now, the dropdown menu is initially hidden, which is ok, but the x-on:click is not working. I already tried testing it with an alert inside x-on:click but it still doesn't work. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the table is using DatatablesJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and removing the "$(document).ready" around my Datatable call solved the problem :

Before :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false, targets: 0 }
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        paging: true,
        ordering: true,
        autoWidth: false
    });
});
```

And now :

```js
$('.table').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, targets: 0 }
    ],
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    paging: true,
    ordering: true,
    autoWidth: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found using Alpine init event helped.

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    $('.table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {orderable: false, targets: 0}
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        paging: true,
        ordering: true,
        autoWidth: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the $(document).ready function solves the conflict

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).